# how to make index.xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm making a website based in xml/xslt.

Is it possible to make this webpage found immediately similar to what index.html does?  It doesn't behave the same when you rename the file index.xml

Comment: that'd depend on which webserver you're using (apache? iis?) and how you configure the default document.

Comment: You mean like http://www.skechers.com/ ?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, which I am not sure of, you would probably have to configure your web server to do that.

Have a look here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-display-or-change-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml/

That assumes you use Apache.